# Extract all Rules from Plot function

Tags: filtering, rule

Let's say I would like to know all the `Rule`s that apply to `PlotTheme->"Detailed"`.
I tried

```
Select[FullForm[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]], Head[#] == Rule &, Infinity]
```

but I get the Error/Warning that `FullForm` was called with 0 arguments, which doesn't make sense to me. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: You should use `Cases` instead of `Select` like this: ```Cases[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
 x_ /; Head[x] === Rule, Infinity
 ]```

Comment: In general if you are looking for rules you would also need to check for `RuleDelayed`, e.g., `Cases[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], x_ /; (Head[x] === Rule || Head[x] === RuleDelayed), Infinity]`. In this particular case that only adds one `DisplayFunction :> Identity`

Answer (score 10):

You can get the options associated with the plot theme `"Detailed"` using the (undocumented) internal function `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme ``:

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Detailed", Plot] // Column
```

[image]

See also: [Related Q/As](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=resolvePlotTheme)

If you need the options for the legended graphics object produced by

```
 plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

you can use `Part`:

```
Head /@ {plot, plot[[1]], plot[[2]]}
```

> ```
> {Legended, Graphics, Placed}
> ```

```
plot[[1, 2]]
```

[image]